# Regexp to remove all special characters in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to basicaly clean urls that have special characters in it, like so:

```
http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=**cr%c3%83%c2%a9er***
```

I would like to replace `**cr%c3%83%c2%a9er***` by `**créer**`

and more generally all characters like `À Á Â à á â È É Ê è é ê
Ì Í Î ì í î Ò Ó Ô ò ó ô
Ù Ú Û ù ú û`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it more general

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
                retStr = encodeURI(retStr);
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var u=decodeURI("http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=cr%c3%83%c2%a9er*");
// u is "http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=crÃ©er*"

var u=decodeURI("http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=cr%C3%A9er*");
// u is "http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=créer*"

var u=decodeURI("http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=%C3%A9%C3%A8%C3%A0%C3%A7%C3%B9%C3%A2%C3%AA%C3%AE*");
// u is "http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=éèàçùâêî*"
```

Read more:

MDN decodeURI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

MDN decodeURIComponent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

```
 var u=decodeURI("http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=%C3%80%C3%81%C3%82%C3%A0%C3%A1%C3%A2%C3%88%C3%89%C3%8A%C3%A8%C3%A9%C3%AA%C3%8C%C3%8D%C3%8E%C3%AC%C3%AD%C3%AE%C3%92%C3%93%C3%94%C3%B2%C3%B3%C3%B4%C3%99%C3%9A%C3%9B%C3%B9%C3%BA%C3%BB*");
 // u is "http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=ÀÁÂàáâÈÉÊèéêÌÍÎìíîÒÓÔòóôÙÚÛùúû*"
```

Comment: can we make not only for the créer case but more broadly for characters like é è à ç ù â ê î

Comment: Yes. See updated answer. And read in MDN. This must works for all unicode characters.

Comment: hmmm, i'm no js expert :( maybe my question is not clear...what i'd like to do is if some characters are found in the url then clean the url i thought regexp would be the answer but i'm not sure!!!

Comment: i added a more detailed list of characters in my question

Comment: Your Q. sounds: "how to __remove__". But inside Q., You ask about __replace__. I think, you need to replace all encoded values (such as %c3 ...) with decoded equivalent (non-standard latin letters) and get URL in decoded (human readable) view. If it's right, then you can use decodeURI to do this work. If I mistaken about your real needs, then I do not know, sorry.

Comment: i guess i'd like to decode ttp://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=cr%c3%83%c2%a9er* so it looks like that ttp://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=créer

Comment: but not only for créer but all words that may have accents in it

Comment: "cr%c3%83%c2%a9er*" decoded as "crÃ©er*" not "créer". "créer" is "cr%C3%A9er*". Are you sure? In any case: for decoding url you must use decodeURI. Regular expressions cannot be used for decoding. You can make some test: copy into clipboard encoded URL from browser address bar for you real site. then go to "developer tools" in browser (in IE, in Chrome) in firebug in FF. In developers tools open javascript console, write in console: _decodeURI("")_ and past between quotes inside decodeURI() your real URL from clipboard. Then press enter (or click "execute"). Result is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not something very generic and you have special characters and phrases that you want to replace, you could map your special characters/phrases to their replacements and then decode the string and replace each of them:

```
var replacements = {
    "crÃÂ©er" : "créer", // this is a phrase
    "Ã" : "é",
    "Â" : "e",
    "©" : ""
};
var url = "http://172.23.113.79/recherche/pages/Results.aspx?k=**cr%c3%83%c2%a9er***";
var decoded = unescape(url); // or decodeURI(url);
for(var key in replacements)
    decoded = decoded.replace(key,replacements[key]);
```

Comment: well, forget about créer the characters that i would like to clean are  éèàçùâêî